# Regex for comma-separated values of specific pattern

Tags: regex

Given a string such as

```
cite{AA,BBB, C}  skip{DD}   cite{EE,F}
```

, I am trying to extract the comma-separated strings in the specific tag (in this case, named as `cite`) using Regex.
Thus, the output for the above string should result in

```
AA
BBB
C
EE
F
```

I think `/cite{(.+?)}/` selects strings in `\cite{....}` form, but how do we then split the string in this output?
I find that some expressions like `[^,(?! )]+` split the strings based on comma, but I cannot find a way to couple these two things.

Comment: You need to use programming language means for splitting with a comma, in C#, `str.Split(',')` could do if you pass the Group 1 value.

Comment: I misunderstood the `'cite'` was to be matched and thought that `'{DD}'` was skipped because it contained just one element. In retrospect my assumption doesn't seem so bright and requiring `'cite'` to be matched appears to simplify things. Unfortunately, I can't fix my answer for several hours because Mr. Sandman refuses to let me continue. I therefore deleted it and will undelete after I've fixed it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland What I intended was capturing contents inside tag named `site` only. Actually this command comes from from latex, which has commands such as `\cite{..}, \bold{...}, ` or `\mathrm{...}`. I'm trying to capture contents only in `\cite{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the string were

```
cite{AA,BBB, C}  skip{DD} GG  cite{EE,F}
     ^^ ^^^  ^                     ^^ ^
```

We want to match the five substrings indicated by the carets.

If the regex engine supports variable-length lookbehinds we could use the regular expression

```
(?<=\bcite{[^{}]*?)[A-Z]+(?=[^{}]*})
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbcite%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%3f%29%5bA-Z%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%29&i=cite%7bAA%2cBBB%2c+C%7d++skip%7bDD%7d+GG++cite%7bEE%2cF%7d+cite%7bGG%7d+cite%7bH%2cI%2cJ%2c+K%7d) (click the "Context" tab at the link to see the matches).

This regex can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=         # begin a positive lookbehind 
  \bcite     # match literal preceded by a word break
  {          # match character
  [^{}]*?    # match zero or more chars other than braces, lazily
)            # end positive lookbehind
[A-Z]+       # match >= 1 uppercase letters
(?=          # begin positive lookahead
  [^{}]*?    # match zero or more chars other than braces, then '}'    
)            # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: cool idea. When I tried this it didn't capture the `C` entry. Also, it needs to account for the `skip` word, regardless of comma.

Comment: I misunderstood the `'cite'` was to be matched and thought that `'{DD}'` was skipped because it contained just one element. In retrospect my assumption doesn't seem so bright and requiring `'cite'` to be matched appears to simplify things. Unfortunately, I can't fix it for several hours because Mr. Sandman refuses to let me continue.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on the comma using a lookbehind, checking for the `cite{` prefix, for example:

- [`(?!<=cite{.*),`](https://regex101.com/r/kX4L3w/1)

[image]

But outside of using a programming language, I'm not sure how you would capture what you want if it's not fixed length, in a single regex. Though if it is fixed-width, you could do something like this:

- [`cite{([A-Z]+)(?:,\s*([A-Z]+))?(?:,\s*([A-Z]+))?}`](https://regex101.com/r/Fv0SGO/1)

[image]